# App store submission, metadata rejected because of chat room option

Tags: ios, app-store, metadata, chat

"We are reviewing your app and have found issues with the following guideline:

3.8

We found that the rating you've selected is not consistent with the content of your app, as required by the App Store Review Guidelines.

Since your application offers a chat room option, this should be reflected in the frequency choice in the Ratings section.

To update the rating you must edit the App details in iTunes Connect. Select Manage Your Applications, open the App Details view and click on Edit Information. From the Edit Application view, select the Ratings tab and select the desired rating. Don't forget to save your changes when done.

If your iTunes Connect Application State is Metadata Rejected, we do NOT require a new binary. In iTunes Connect > Manage Your Applications, select your app and click View Details.

- Click Edit in the Metadata section
- Revise the desired metadata values
- Click "Save" at the bottom of the screen
- Once you click Save, you will see the "Submit New Metadata" button in the top right. Click "Submit New Metadata"

I viewed the Review Guidelines, and looked at the metadata, and I still have no idea which part should I change. Which frequency option do I have to change?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the section for giving your app a rating (4+, 13+, 17+, etc.). You need to choose a different rating because it seems that you did not mention chat room capabilities in your application. Follow the instructions that Apple gave you and just modify your rating.

Comment: Problem is, I'm not sure which part of the rating should I change. The closest that I can find is Humor/Profanity, Mature/suggestive themes, Medical/Treatment Information and Alcohol, Tobacco, or Drug Use or References (its a sports related app)

Comment: I would say Mature/Suggestive themes would be the option to change. Make it the middle option. That should do it.